# Update an SKLabelNode to have a different text field later on by a condition basis. Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

using latest swift in SpriteKit.
I would like to update the text within a defined label in SKLabelNode.
Take a look below. It does not show errors to run, but it does not change the text node. Any help?

```
    func lookforThings() {
        if player.position.x > -240 {
            let label0 = SKLabelNode()
            addChild(label0)
            label0.text = "Start searching the forest for your friends..."
            label0.position.x = 12
            label0.position.y = 112
            label0.zPosition = 0.5
            label0.fontSize = 12
            label0.fontColor = SKColor.green
            if player.position.x > 100 {
                label0.text = ""
            }
        }
```

Label0 is initialized above, then set at a value, using the .text attribute.
Following that, label0 is changed to be "" or empty in other words. As a way to remove the SKLabelNode from the scene at this case. Is there another way of doing this? Why did it not change the text. It stayed say "Start searching the forest for your friends..." even after the next if case was taken.

Comment: player doesn't know anything about the label object you are creating inside a function.  When you run the function, you are telling the class that you want to set an empty text to the label if its x position is greater than 100.  Or set it to "Start searching dah, dah, dah."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat guessing since you haven't shown enough to be sure, but every time you call `lookForThings` you're creating a new label and adding it to the scene.  Any previous labels added aren't being affected, so likely you're building up a stack of labels, most of which are showing the "Start searching" message.  They're all at the same place so you're not noticing them as distinct.

Probably you want one label that should appear when the player is in the relevant region and be removed when not.  Something like this:

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
  var searchingLabel: SKLabelNode?

  func lookForThings() {
    if player.position.x > -240 && player.position.x <= 100 {
      // Show the searching message
      guard searchingLabel == nil else { return }  // Already shown
      let label = SKLabelNode()
      addChild(label)
      label.text = ... // Set up the label as desired
      searchingLabel = label
    } else {
      // Don't show the message
      guard let label = searchingLabel else { return }  // Already removed
      label.removeFromParent()
      searchingLabel = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is one way to go about. I ended up using:

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the child node this way, later on in the code, or with a time variable duration.

label.run(SKAction.sequence([ SKAction.wait(forDuration: 14), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))